# CheckPoint SmartDashboard report file (mht) to csv file

Tags: checkpoint

Does anyone knows a way to export the CheckPoint SmartDashboard Report (mht file) to one or multiple csv file(s)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question, but if you want to visualize your rulebase, you can use CPUploader (http://wormnet.nl/). You copy the relevant files to the tools directory and it creates an HTML file with the complete Rulebase for you.

The site is very old, this is still working though (last version I did it with was R76 I think).